# How to Consume Web Api in xamarin CrossPlatform Application

Tags: android, api, xamarin

I have created web api that retrieves data from SQL database. I need to consume web api in xamrin for android and xamarin for iOS. as of now xamarin for android. I am not sure how to call GET and Post method based on button click event.

Here is web api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MvcAppDept.Controllers
{
public class DeptController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<Dept> Get()
    {
        AndroidAppDBEntities db = new AndroidAppDBEntities();
        var data = from dept in db.Depts orderby dept.no select dept;
        return data.ToList();
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public Dept Get(int id)
    {
        AndroidAppDBEntities db = new AndroidAppDBEntities();
        var data = from dept in db.Depts where dept.no == id select dept;
        return data.SingleOrDefault();
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(Dept obj)
    {
        AndroidAppDBEntities db = new AndroidAppDBEntities();
        db.Depts.Add(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id,Dept obj)
    {
        AndroidAppDBEntities db = new AndroidAppDBEntities();
        var data = from dept in db.Depts where dept.no == id select dept;
        Dept old = data.SingleOrDefault();
        old.no = obj.no;
        old.name = obj.name;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        AndroidAppDBEntities db = new AndroidAppDBEntities();
        var data = from dept in db.Depts where dept.no == id select dept;
        Dept obj = data.SingleOrDefault();
        db.Depts.Remove(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
 }
}


Global.asax.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

 namespace MvcAppDept
{


public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();


    }
   }
```

}

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
namespace DeptAndroidApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "DeptAndroidApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button GetButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.GetButton);
            var txtValue1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtValue1);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtValue1.Text);
            var No = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.No);
            var Name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Name);
            //GetButton.Click += GetDept(id); 
            GetButton.Click+=async(sender,args)=>{
           //error  Cannot await 'DeptAndroidApp.dept                  
           Dept dept=await GetDept(id);
                No.Text=dept.No;
                Name.Text=dept.name}
        }
        //Error The return type ofasync method must be void,task orTask<T>
        public async Dept GetDept(int id)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://****.***/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new               System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var result= await client.GetAsync(string.Format("/api/dept/{0}",id));
               return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dept>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());                }       
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would use this service from just about any project (including Xamarin projects).

First, get rid of the line in your Global.asax file that says this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

Generally speaking this is bad practice. You want to have at least the XML and JSON formatters available because in a restful environment it is up to the consumers to determine what type of serialization they need/want.

Next, I would use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class to interact with this service.

Interacting with the Web Api service from this point is fairly straightforward.  Here are some examples.

```
public async List<Dept> GetDepts()
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<ipAddress:port>/");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

          return await client.GetAsync("/api/dept");
     }
}

public async Task<Dept> GetDept(int id)
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<ipAddress:port>/");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

          var result = await client.GetAsync(string.format("/api/dept/{0}", id));

          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dept>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
     }
}

public async Task AddDept(Dept dept)
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<ipAddress:port>/");

          await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/dept", dept);
     }
}

public async Task UpdateDept(Dept dept)
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<ipAddress:port>/");

          await client.PutAsJsonAsync(string.format("/api/dept/{0}", dept.no), dept);
     }
}

public async Task DeleteDept(int id)
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<ipAddress:port>/");

          client.DeleteAsync(string.format("/api/dept/{0}", id));
     }
}
```

That should get you started in the right direction anyway.  This could definitely get cleaned up and I wrote it freehand so there may be some typos.

*Update*

Update your MainActivity.cs

Instead of `int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtValue1)`

Use

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtValue1.Text);
```

Instead of `GetButton.Click += GetDept(id);`

Use

```
GetButton.Click += async (sender, args) => {
   var dept = await GetDept(id);

   No.Text = dept.no;
   Name.Text = dept.name
}
```

Comment: Thank you again! can I add Systen.net.http in xamarin for android project?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add it directly to your Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: hey do you want me to replace  my web api methods as listed above with your code snippest or where to use your methods I am not getting that. Where  to add async methods.

Comment: No, leave your Web Api methods just the way they are.  Take my code and use it in your Xamarin.Android project.  Just like in your WCF post, when the user clicks a button to Add a deptartment, call the AddDept method in my sample.  If the user wants to get a list of the current departments, call the GetDepts method in my code.  This should all be done from the Xamarin.Android app.

Comment: My pleasure.  I love this stuff!  :-)

Comment: do we need to add api reference I am getting an error for Dept

Comment: No, you don't need to add any references. You will need to copy your class definition of Dept from your Web Api project into your Xamarin.Android project so that they both know what a Dept class looks like.

Comment: Also getting an error at line GetButton.Click += GetDept(id); "cannot inplicilty convert DeptAndroidApp.Dept to Systen.event handler

Comment: I think return type of GetDept must be something task if it is Dept then it is not accepting it.

Comment: Change "GetButton.Click += GetDept(id);" to "GetButton.Click += async (sender, args) => { var dept = await GetDept(id); txtValue1.Text = dept.name; };" Not sure what you want to do with the Dept object once you get it back.  This will stick the name of the Dept in the TextView.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Try that.  I'm guessing you were getting an error trying to get the id from the TextView?

Comment: I have added the code for reference with errors. I made changes mentioned by you.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that.  Chage "public async Dept GetDept(int id)" to "public async Task<Dept> GetDept(int id)". I also updated my answer.

Comment: return await client.GetAsync(string.Format("/api/dept/{0}",id)); error :   Cannot implicitly convert 'system.Net.Http.HttpResponceMessage' to DeptAndroidApp.Dept

Comment: Use Nuget to add JSON.net to your project. Then you will need to do something like this: var result = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("/api/dept/{0}", id)); return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dept>( await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());" Sorry, I wrote all this freehand originally and messed up a little.

Comment: No need to sorry you are helping a lot.And I appreciate that, I am a newbie to .net as well as mobile app. I will try above mentioned steps and let you know.

Comment: It removed errors but when I build the project it throws an errorError 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DeptAndroidApp.Dept>' is less accessible than method 'DeptAndroidApp.MainActivity.GetDept(int)' C:\Users\agrawpa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DeptAndroidApp\DeptAndroidApp\MainActivity.cs 36 33 DeptAndroidApp

Comment: I have modified my Mainactivity.cs