# How to call a ASP.Net C# WCFService on Android Studio?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

Can anyone help me on how to call a C# WCF web service from Android Studio. My webservice is "http://192.168.1.100:93/MyService.svc?wsdl"

MyService.svc

```
namespace MyServiceApp
{
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
       public string Hello(string strName)
        {
            string strResult="";
            strResult = "Hello " + strName;
            return strTest;
        }
    }
}
```

IMyService.cs

```
namespace MyServiceApp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Hello(string strName);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to connect to WCF service from Android studio, but you can still consume it (WCF Service) as SOAP/POST.

To get you started - look at previous answer by [Andy white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)  - I'm using this approach as well and it is working quite well.

Note : You might want to inspect packets that service sends/gets via some tool like fiddler.

Alternatively for people that are using Xamarin (I know that it doesn't help in your situation, but it might be usefull for other people) - I would look at [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/wcf) (or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751143/consume-wcf-service-in-xamarin-cross-platform-application) if you like it more).